# Converting Fractions to Decimals

Tags: php, html-entities

I have strings with HTML fractions. How can I convert them to decimals?
Do I need to replace the fractions with their values? But in the case of 1 ⅔ it is not so easy, because I need to add the 1.

```
<?php

$mappingArr = [
  '½' => 1/2,
  '⅓' => 1/3,
  '⅔' => 2/3,
  '¼' => 1/4,
  '¾' => 3/4,
  '⅕' => 1/5,
  '⅖' => 2/5,
  '⅗' => 3/5,
  '⅘' => 4/5,
  '⅙' => 1/6,
  '⅚' => 5/6,
  '⅐' => 1/7,
  '⅛' => 1/8,
  '⅜' => 3/8,
  '⅝' => 5/8,
  '⅞' => 7/8,
  '⅑' => 1/9,
  '⅒' => 1/10
];

$fractionString1 = "⅓ Test something else";
$fractionString2 = "1½ Test (test)";
$fractionString3 = "1 ⅔ Test, test";

// how to convert HTML vulgar fractions to decimals?

// result should be
$fractionStringDecimal1 = "0.33 Test something else";
$fractionStringDecimal2 = "1.5 Test (test)";
$fractionStringDecimal3 = "1.67 Test, test";
?>
```

Comment: You will need a mapping for this like: `$mappingArr = ['⅓' => 1/3, '½' => 1/2, ...]` after you need to split by space. if no space (like 1½) you split by char.

Comment: I updated the mapping array in my code example.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to iterate over each character and check, if it is an number oder a fraction char.

The code could be something like the folowing.
I am using unicode string operations (mb_substr and mb_strlen) because the fraction chars are uncode chars.

```
function convertFractionToDecimals($str){
    $result = "";
    $number = null;
    
    //iterate over each unicode char in the string
    for($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($str); $i++){
        //if current char is a number, save it temporarly
        if(is_numeric(mb_substr($str, $i, 1))){
            if($number == null){
                $number = mb_substr($str, $i, 1);
            } else {
                $number .= mb_substr($str, $i, 1);
            }
            continue;
        }
           
        //if the current char is a fraction char, resolve it
        if(isFraction(mb_substr($str, $i, 1))){
           if($number != null){
               $result .= $number + resolveFraction(mb_substr($str, $i, 1));
           } else {
               $result .= resolveFraction(mb_substr($str, $i, 1));
           }
            
           continue;
        }
        
        //if we have a number in front of the current char, that is a space, check if next char is a space or a fraction
        if($number != null && mb_substr($str, $i, 1) === ' ' && $i + 1 < mb_strlen($str) && (mb_substr($str, $i+1, 1) === ' ' || isFraction(mb_substr($str, $i+1, 1)))){
           continue;
        }
           
        if($number != null){
            $result .= $number;
            $number = null;
        }
           
        //a char, that is not a number nor a fraction will be just added to result
        $result .= mb_substr($str, $i, 1);
    }
    
    
    return $result;
}

function getFractionMap(){
    return $mappingArr = [
      '½' => 1/2,
      '⅓' => 1/3,
      '⅔' => 2/3,
      '¼' => 1/4,
      '¾' => 3/4,
      '⅕' => 1/5,
      '⅖' => 2/5,
      '⅗' => 3/5,
      '⅘' => 4/5,
      '⅙' => 1/6,
      '⅚' => 5/6,
      '⅐' => 1/7,
      '⅛' => 1/8,
      '⅜' => 3/8,
      '⅝' => 5/8,
      '⅞' => 7/8,
      '⅑' => 1/9,
      '⅒' => 1/10
    ];
}
           
function isFraction($char) {
   return array_key_exists($char, getFractionMap());    
}
           
function resolveFraction($char){
    return getFractionMap()[$char];       
}
```